# Arm platform, Why the thread was blocked in popen function?

Tags: linux, ping, popen

In my program, there is a thread that calls the `popen` function to execute a `ping` command. After letting it run for a few days, sometimes the thread will block in `popen`.  I found some information about the `popen`, but can not get the result.

Below is the output of a run.

### Normal:

> test popen before 
>   test fgets before 
>   test fgets after

### Block:

> test popen before

### Code:

```
int ping_fun(char *p_ip_addr)
{
    FILE *ptr = NULL;
    char buff[512];
    char ps[128];
    int ret_value = 0;


    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(ps));

    sprintf(ps,"ping -c 5 %s 2>&1 | grep -c '64 bytes from'", p_ip_addr);

    printf("test popen before\n");
    ptr = popen(ps, "r");

    if (NULL != ptr)
    {
        printf("test fgets before\n");
        fgets(buff, 512, ptr);
        printf("test fgets after\n");
        ret_value = atoi(buff);
        if (ret_value > 0)  //ping success
        {
            //do something .....
        }
        pclose(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("test popen fail\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *Found some information about `popen`*?  You mean `popen` returned something or your read the `man` page?

Comment: yes, if popen returned, it will output the print information "test fgets before " or "test popen fail", but not any output when blocked.

Comment: Did you run `ps` to see that you don't have 1000s of zombie processes?